# virtual-kubelet Provider exec API return WebSocket， How do I implement RunInContainer？

Tags: go, kubernetes

virtual-kubelet Provider exec API return WebSocket， How do I implement RunInContainer？

The following code is the implementation of the K8S API， I want to connect to a websockect API

```
func (p *MopProvider) RunInContainer(ctx context.Context, namespace, name, container string, cmd []string, attach api.AttachIO) error {
    log.G(context.TODO()).Infof("receive ExecInContainer %q", container)
    req := p.K8SClient.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Namespace(p.config.Namespace).
        Name(name).
        SubResource("exec")
    req.VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
        Container: container,
        Command:   cmd,
        Stdin:     true,
        Stdout:    true,
        Stderr:    true,
        TTY:       true,
    }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    executor, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(p.K8SClient.GetConfig(), "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "NewSPDYExecutor error")
    }
    return executor.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:             attach.Stdin(),
        Stdout:            attach.Stdout(),
        Stderr:            attach.Stderr(),
        TerminalSizeQueue: newTerminalSizeQueue(attach.Resize()),
        Tty:               attach.TTY(),
    })
}
```